# how to apply event on moving image(Animating from top to bottom)

Tags: android, android-animation

i have an example,in this the image moves from top to bottom and bottom to top,this is fine but my requirement is i want to generates some events on the screen by clicking on that moving image thats it .
please any one help me.

```
 xml file:

     <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="406dp"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:background="@anim/graphics" >

     <!-- <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/androidimage"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:onClick="imageButtonClicked"
      android:src="@drawable/android" 
      android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"/> -->

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/androidimage"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:onClick="imageButtonClicked"
      android:src="@drawable/android" 
      android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

  </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [nineoldandroids library](http://nineoldandroids.com/).
use ObjectAnimator calss to animate.